# Message to all subscribers

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

i use Azure Service Bus and want to send message to all subscribers in Topic. Client's app is written in JavaFX and for handling i use next code:

```
IMessageHandler messageHandler = new IMessageHandler() {


        // callback invoked when the message handler loop has obtained a message
        public CompletableFuture<Void> onMessageAsync(IMessage message) {
            String body = new String(message.getBody());
            System.out.println(body);
            decorator.showToastWithTitleAndBody("", body);
            return receiveClient.abandonAsync(message.getLockToken());
        }

        public void notifyException(Throwable throwable, ExceptionPhase exceptionPhase) {
            System.out.printf(exceptionPhase + "-" + throwable.getMessage());
        }
    };



    receiveClient.registerMessageHandler(
            messageHandler,
            // callback invoked when the message handler has an exception to report
            // 1 concurrent call, messages are auto-completed, auto-renew duration
            new MessageHandlerOptions(1, true, Duration.ofSeconds(1)));
```

In "onMessageAsync" method i use abandonAsync to not delete message and for the next recivers will get message. But i got lot's of message with the same content in each app instance. If i use completeAsync method message will remove and no one else will get it.

Is it real to send message to all subscribers in Topic without removing and withou duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message handler is configured to automatically complete the incoming messages. Yet, within callback method messages are abandoned. That means they'll never be auto-completed, and rather redelivered as many times as the `MaxDeliveryCount` of the subscription is configured to (assuming you're fetching messages from the subscription).

The handler code should **not** abandon and either let auto-completion takes it's place or, alternatively, disable auto-completion and invoke `.completeAsync()` once handler is done with the incoming message.

Also, auto-renew is defined as 1 second. That's off. This should be at least longer than `LockDuration` period or not specified at all.

> Is it real to send message to all subscribers in Topic without removing and withou duplicate?

Yes. You won't need de-duplication as it's not an issue of duplicates being **sent**, but duplicate **processing**.

Comment: I set auto-renew 40 seconds and LockDuration 30, but when i invoke completeAsync() only one app get message.

Comment: "only one all gets the message". I'm not going to dive into your design, but are all apps reading from the _same_ subscription? If that's the case, it's working as intended. Either you should have a queue per app (which is an aweful suggestion on its own and I should shower after posting this) or review your overall design, as it feels your doing something that should not be done with an ESB.

Comment: may i create one subscription for one application or is it bad idea? I need to send push like notification to desktop application on Javafx.

Comment: Feels like a misuse of the Service Bus. You can have N number of clients that will have to have a connection string to the service. What happens if you need to regenerate that connection string? I'd use some client-notification library that would push messages to the client. I.e. a service that would receive ASB message from the subscription and broadcast a push notification to all clients. Example in the .NET world would be SignalR. Which is also available as an Azure service.

Comment: ok, thank you, i understood. You completely answered my question.